# Windows 10, virtual desktops. Is it possible to share some apps between the desktops

Tags: windows-10, skype, virtual-desktop

I'm just starting to use virtual desktops and I use it to split work & non-work activity. However, some application I want on both virtual desktops like Skype, outlook,.. . Outlook allows you to start twice but starting up skype just makes you switch to the desktop that is active. Both is undesirable